# Lightning Web Components - Benefits and Support

Tags: lightning-web-components

Salesforce announced Lightning Web Components in Dec. 2018. In comparison to the existing Aura Framework:

- What are the benefits of using Lightning Web Components? / How much faster are they?
- Where are Lightning Web Components supported?
- How are LWC compatible to existing Aura Components?

Comment: The Lightning Component framework now has two programming models: the new Lightning Web Components model, and Aura Components, which is the original model. Components build using these models can interoperate and work side-by-side in the same app. To use features that LWC may not yet support, wrap a Lightning web component in an thin Aura component wrapper.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> If you are considering LWC, and would like see code samples and how to implement LWC, including interoperability with Aura, take a look at the lwc-recipes sample app. It's maintained by Salesforce Developer Relations. You can find it (and contribute to it) on [github](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes).

## What are the benefits of using Lightning Web Components?

LWC is built on web standards for almost all of the code involved, with a minimal amount of "custom code" that represents the core Aura runtime that underlies both technologies (as mentioned in the opening blog post). This means they are more secure (LWC adds CSS isolation, leverages native DOM support for better performance, and uses more web-standards JavaScript that can be optimized better).

Also, LWC automatically provides polyfills for older browsers, rather than having code silently (or often not-so-silently) fail on IE 11 and older versions of Safari/Chrome/Firefox. In addition, we have new component "types", such as service components; they have no UI so they use no markup, but can export methods for other components to import in just a single line of code. No more static resources just to share code within a set of components.

LWC itself has a richer API based on the UI-API for better performance and less Apex to write, and calling Apex is now a less painful experience. API support for third-party APIs is also improved, allowing you to call code in a safe, secure manner in ways that are not possible or required Apex code in Aura components.

LWC provides support for the [Jest](https://jestjs.io) testing framework through the sfdx-lwc-jest [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest). This means you can now write unit tests for your client-side logic in a standard format. In Aura, you were expected to find your own testing framework, like Jasmine or something else. This will help improve your client logic, the same way that Apex unit tests can help improve your server-side logic.

LWC leverages a combination of knowledge of Aura and web components (the general standards), so developers with experience in web components can get in to LWC faster, and developers familiar with Aura will already know most of the major standard components already; you just need to translate them from the old syntax to the new. Should you decide to port an Aura component to LWC, it will be a straight-forward process, since they can be converted almost 1:1 (there are some major differences, but those are very limited).

So, better security, better testing, better browser compatibility, better performance, generally smaller components in terms of overall markup and script size, less need for Apex, less need for multiple Apex controllers, and strong leverage of already existing/established knowledge and skills from both Salesforce development and general web component development.

## How much faster are they?

In the opening blog post, they say "we don't know, but it's better" (paraphrased, of course). Salesforce also mentions that customers have reported that Lightning Experience is faster than it was a year ago, and that's partly because the UI is now mostly LWC, and the all/most standard Lightning part of the Lightning Component library is LWC under the covers, which has contributed to faster Aura performance. So, anecdotally, it's better. But we're probably not going to know until someone with a lot of time on their hands converts a bunch of components and does a side-by-side comparison.

## Where are Lightning Web Components supported?

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.get_started_supported_experiences), as of Spring '20, LWC support is as follows:

### Supported features

- Lightning Experience
- Salesforce App
- Lightning Communities
- Lightning App Builder
- Community Builder
- Standalone Apps
- Lightning Components for Visualforce
- Lightning Out (beta)
- Custom Tabs
- Utility Bars
- Flows
- First-Generation Managed Packages
- Second-Generation Managed Packages
- Unlocked Packages
- Unmanaged Packages
- Change Sets
- Metadata API—LightningComponentBundle
- Tooling API—LightningComponentBundle, LightningComponentResource
- EMP API
- Embedded Service Chat
- Gmail and Outlook integration

### Unsupported features

- Salesforce Console APIs (Navigation Item API, Workspace API, Utility Bar API)
- URL Addressable Tabs
- Conversation Toolkit API, Omni Toolkit API, Quick Action API
- Standard Action Overrides, Custom Actions, Global Actions, List View Actions, Related List View Actions
- Chatter Extensions

One additional missing piece is the lack of built-in documentation. Aura provided the Auradoc feature in the Aura bundle. No such feature exists yet for LWC.

## How are LWC compatible to existing Aura Components?

The syntax itself is pretty different, so there will be significant portions of your code you'll have to rewrite to convert an Aura component to an LWC. That said, if you're familiar with Aura, it's easy to do the conversion, and familiarity with React and other JavaScript web component frameworks will aid in helping understand LWC. Even better, LWC experience will make it easier to learn other standards-based web component frameworks, unlike Aura, which is proprietary in comparison.

LWC components can be placed in Aura components, but Aura components may not be used in LWC components. For this reason, you'll want to start converting your code from the utility/widget portion of your components before converting main components. You'll need to check the "supported experience" list above before trying to convert top-level Aura components to LWC.

Both Aura and LWC components can coexist in the same Lightning page. With the [beta](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_message_channel.htm) release of Lightning Message Service they can communicate with each other (and with Visualforce pages) via events.

In cases where you can't use LWC immediately, you can always put those on a backlog or, just not worry about it, since Aura will be around for a while. The more components you convert to LWC, the better performance you can expect from your components overall. Converting your core UI components from Aura to LWC won't require any major inconvenience in your existing Aura components, because they look like Aura components in Aura.

## To Sum Up

Since its initial release a year ago LWC has had significant improvements such that unless you are inhibited by one of the specific limitations listed above, there is nothing preventing you from building any custom UI project using LWC.

Furthermore, everything in LWC is far simpler than Aura. There are fewer overall "gotchas" than Aura. Finally, if you're just starting out developing on the platform there's a lot less to learn to begin using LWC, because it's a very lean API, in a good way.

Comment: +1 for the elaborative answer. One thing I was confused about supported containers though when I See the components in the component library's component reference they say ther'e supported in the _Lightning Out / Visualforce_ Not sure why does it say other way round in the dev library though Eg: the image posted for lightning experience support!

Comment: @codeyinthecloud As far as I can tell, the Component Reference is wrong, the Developer Guide is right. Lightning out does not appear to be supported. They probably just copied the data from the Aura version of the docs, which isn't strictly correct.

Comment: This makes more sense, thanks for finding! Do you think we need to report it to the dev relations team to avoid this confusion?

Comment: @codeyinthecloud Yeah, they should either clarify or correct. If there is a way to do so, great, but everything I tried either met compiler failures or an internal server error. Otherwise, definitely should be fixed, because they put the components before the documentation, so a lot of people aren't likely to immediately see the limitations page.

Comment: Thanks for all that. Looks like Spring 19 is the right time for me to learn all I can about LWC but not use them yet - because our customers really love Console and I don't want to be locked out of providing Consle-friendly functionality.

Comment: @CharlesT It'll be a complicated landscape of development for the next 1-2 years, I expect, based on Aura components, but it should settle down once feature parity is achieved, assuming that's the end goal of the roadmap.

Comment: You can define your event attributes, including validation. Just build an ES6 module that extends `CustomEvent`, and add your custom things there.

Comment: @muenzpraeger Thanks for that information. I was more referring to how Aura has an aura:event where you can define attributes and include an auradocs file, while in LWC, you can't. A custom module could help runtime and tests, but it won't help with documentation, which is my primary concern at the moment. I feel that documentation should have been part of v1, but hopefully we'll get an alternative soon.

Comment: Frankly I am surprised that the progress from closed pilot to "GA next release" has been so rapid. I expect that with so much functionality still left yet to come, this is going to be a lot like the buggy transition from pre- to post-Locker Service, except a much larger change.

Comment: @CharlesT To be fair, it's actually already been widely used (I noticed this at least as soon as June 2018), they just kept it a poorly kept secret (you would have seen it in the browser's Developer Console). That aside, I agree that we should have documentation and event declarations. But those will be smoothed out in the coming releases.

Comment: @CharlesT just look at the source of the brand new Flow Designer - all built upon LWC.

Comment: It says quick action api not supported. does that mean I cannot create a quick action out of a lwc?

Comment: @SallyRothroat That's correct--for now. It is commonly theorized that future releases may support this and other contexts. Unfortunately, we don't know when, or if, this might occur.

Comment: @sfdcfox If I understand correctly ECMAScript is the standards for javascript that are followed while working on LWC. What are the recommended javascript frameworks for LWC? Documentation refers to Modern ECMAScript javascript, can one use js frameworks like react or angular js in LWC?

Comment: @sfdcfox I updated the feature support list and made some other edits, trying to stay true to your original post. This answer would be a good candidate to become a community wiki, IMO.

Comment: @pchittum Sure, I don't have a problem with an answer like this being a wiki, as LWC is constantly evolving, and I only have limited time. I'll amend this, and thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

> What are the benefits of using Lightning Web Components? / How much
>   faster are they?

[Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/introducing-lightning-web-components.html) is the Salesforce implementation of that new breed of lightweight frameworks built on web standards. It leverages custom elements, templates, shadow DOM, decorators, modules, and other new language constructs available in ECMAScript 7 and beyond.Lightning Web Components provides a layer of specialized Salesforce services on top of the core stack, including base lightning components,Lightning Data Service and User Interface API. You're getting more than what you have today with aura components aligning to web standards

**How much faster are they?** Honestly I don't have any metrics to define the speed yet neither are released by salesforce. Look for [performance](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242469/what-are-lightning-web-components) in the answer.

> Where are Lightning Web Components supported?

[image: Supported Experiences]

> How are LWC compatible to existing Aura Components?

An interoperability layer enables Lightning web components and Aura components to work together in an app.

You can write new Lightning web components and add them to apps that contain Aura components. Or, you can iteratively migrate on your schedule by replacing individual Aura components in your app with Lightning web components.

**Compose Aura Components from Lightning Web Components:**
You can compose Aura components from Lightning web components, but not the other way around. To communicate down the hierarchy, parents set properties on children. To decide when and how to nest a Lightning web component in an Aura component, it’s important to understand facets and slots.

In an Aura component, to refer to either Aura components or Lightning web components, use camel case with a colon separating the namespace and the component name.This Aura component is composed of lightning:card, which is a base Lightning component, and c:lwcHelloWorld, which is a Lightning web component.

```
<!-- auraComponent.cmp file -->

<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <lightning:card title="Aura Hello World" iconName="custom:custom30" />

    <c:lwcHelloWorld name="Earthling" />

</aura:component>
```

**Send Events to an Enclosing Aura Component :** To communicate from child to parent, dispatch an event. Lightning web components fire DOM events. An enclosing Aura component can listen for these events, just like an enclosing Lightning web component can. The enclosing Aura component can capture the event and handle it. Optionally, the Aura component can fire an Aura event to communicate with other Aura components or with the app container.

**Use CSS Variables to Reference Aura Design Tokens** Aura component styles cascade on Lightning web components.

Design tokens are named entities that store visual design attributes, such as margins and spacing values, font sizes and families, or hex values for colors.

Design tokens must be defined in an Aura component in the same DOM as your Lightning web component. Then, the Lightning web component can use CSS variable syntax to reference the Aura component’s design token.

**Share JavaScript Code Between LWC and Aura :**
To share JavaScript code between Lightning web components and Aura components, put the code in an ES6 module.

There is a lot more detailed info on the [lwc developer guide](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242603/where-is-the-lightning-web-component-developer-guide) interms of Aura coexistence.

Comment: I have a question about... "Design tokens must be defined in an Aura component in the same DOM as your Lightning web component. Then, the Lightning web component can use CSS variable syntax to reference the Aura component’s design token". Since Design Tokens are defined in a tokens bundle, do you mean that an aura:component in the same DOM must USE the tokens that you want to cascade to your LWC?

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that poor performance is a result of rendering delays, LWCs pretty much resolve that issue.  Rendering is so much faster in LWC due to browser API support in particular that rendering delays are no longer relevant and that is readily seen with side-by-side comparisons of LCs to LWCs.  But if poor performance is due to data issues (such as delays from searching 10 million records without a cache or index) then no amount of rendering improvement in JavaScript would solve the problem.